# SDL Web8 Deployer Service standalone microservice throws error "{"error":"invalid_grant"}"

Tags: web8, deployer, sdl-tridion

Deployer services is running but when i browse http://localhost:8084/httpuload.aspx it throws error -->

{"error":"invalid_grant"}

Any clue guys?

Answer (score 7):

What you are seeing is not actually an error but expected behavior with a default install of the Deployer Micro Service. You have OAuth enabled for your service which is configured in the ambient config file.

The Invalid grant is because when you make a get request with OAuth enabled you must first get a token from the token service, which in turn can be used as a credential for the deployer service.

So in short, you need to do one of the following

1. Disable OAuth (not recomended, but you will be able to view the
   service response)
2. Take a look at Peter's response [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13736/what-should-i-see-after-installing-the-sdl-web8-content-service) which describes how to get a token using a tool like postman and test the services. Or use [this example](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-7BAC5466-3D45-4238-BEBA-0A5DB417C986) from SDL
3. Not worry about it, make sure your deployer is registered with the Discovery Service, and set up Topology Manager to point at the discovery service and test publishing that way.

Comment: Thanks Chris, and do i need to connect TM or Broker db?

Comment: Well if you want your Deployer to store content somewhere, I highly recommend configuring it to point at a Broker DB, but you can still use File System storage if you must. You will also need Topology Manager if you are using the new style of publishing (via Discovery Service).

Comment: You can also use a powershell script to test these services with oAuth https://blog.indivirtual.nl/testing-sdl-web-8-micro-services/