# SDL Web-8, Topology Installation

Tags: topology-manager, discovery-service

I am installing sdlweb8 on a virtual machine as a standlone.

I am trying to run;

```
Add-TtmWebsite -Id visitorsweb -CdEnvironmentId LocalCD -BaseUrls http://localhost:82
```

... but I am getting the following error;

```
Add-TtmWebsite : Unable to save item of type 'WebApplicationData' with id 'visitorsweb_RootWebApp'. One or more errors occurred. An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery Service 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc' in CD Environment 'LocalCD'.  An error occurred while processing this request. Path 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/WebCapabilities' is not allowed At line:1 char:1
+ Add-TtmWebsite -Id visitorsweb -CdEnvironmentId LocalCD -BaseUrls http://localho ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...dWebsiteCommand:AddWebsiteCommand) [Add-TtmWebsite], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddWebsiteCommand
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

I have already run the "discovery-registration.jar" file.

Answer (score 1):

In the Discovery Service Storage Config, at the bottom where the services are listed, please try to access each of the service URLs.  If you are not using OAuth, you can simply do this in the browser.  If you are using OAuth, then follow Peter's tips here, [What should I see after installing the SDL Web8 Content Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13736/what-should-i-see-after-installing-the-sdl-web8-content-service)

or the SDL tips here for getting the token, and using this token to query the service URLs, http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-7BAC5466-3D45-4238-BEBA-0A5DB417C986

Next, you can use the discovery-registration.jar in the config folder of the discovery service, so it will use that cd_storage_conf, and read the capabilities that it thinks it has.

Finally, you could try to run the discovery-registration.jar with the 'sync' command to make sure the capabilities are all synchronized to the DB, etc.

If it is still not working, please post your services in the cd_storage_conf and also the output of the read command from the discovery-registration.jar.