# Discovery Service using HTTPS

Tags: topology-manager, sites-9, https

We have a secure Discovery service using https and are using Tridion Sites 9.  Accessing it from the browser works but when accessing it from the TopologyManager `Add-TtmCdEnvironment`, we get the following error.

> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. The request was aborted:
>   Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

We have not yet followed the instructions for [Securing the microservice with SSL](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-F432E08A-9062-4D53-9F32-10C9661B63DB). I assume this would solve it.  But, why would the request to the MicroServices work in the Browser but not via the PowerShell command?

StackTrace:

> Log Name:      Tridion Source:        Tridion TopologyManager Date:
>   3/19/2019 2:24:30 PM Event ID:      100 Task Category: None Level:
>   Error Keywords:      Classic User:          N/A Computer:
>   CPU_NAME Description: Unable to save item of type
>   'CdEnvironmentData' with id 'DevStaging'. One or more errors
>   occurred. An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery
>   Service 'https://tridion-dev.net:8082/discovery.svc' in CD
>   Environment 'DevStaging'.  The request was aborted: Could not
>   create SSL/TLS secure channel. The request was aborted: Could not
>   create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> Component: Tridion.TopologyManager.Service Errorcode: 12 User: NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> StackTrace Information Details:   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse()   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.GetResponseHelper(ODataRequestMessageWrapper
>   request, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean handleWebException)   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext
>   context, QueryComponents queryComponents)   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.ReturnSingleton[TElement](Expression
>   expression)   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Connectors.CdDiscoveryServiceClient.ExecuteRequestWithRetry(Action
>   action, String cdEnvironmentId)   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Connectors.CdDiscoveryServiceClient.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Connectors.CdDiscoveryServiceClient.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Connectors.CdConnector.d__11.MoveNext()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32
>   millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Connectors.CdConnector.OnCreated(TopologyItemData
>   item, TtmOperationContext context)   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Connectors.CdConnector.OnCreated(TopologyItemData
>   item, TtmOperationContext context)   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.CrossSystemBusinessLogicRegistry.OnCreated(TopologyItemData
>   item, TtmOperationContext context)   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.TopologyItem`1.Create(T item,
>   TtmOperationContext context)   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Service.Controllers.TopologyItemController`1.Create(T
>   entity)   at
>   Tridion.TopologyManager.Service.Controllers.TopologyItemController`1.Post(T
>   entity)   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<GetExecutor>b__3(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__6.MoveNext()

Comment: Is there any error in the discovery service on cd_core.log? can you try to validate in the postman for this URL http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/Environment? for me seems to be a keystore file, not setup correctly

Comment: I have seen that error when SSL is not setup correctly. You can refer some useful responses from https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13736/what-should-i-see-after-installing-the-sdl-web8-content-service. Suggest that you write up a small powershell in your CM (where TopMan is installed), and validate connections and capabilities.

Comment: I have seen a similar error when the server (or NLB) enforces the use of TLS 1.2 (lower versions of SSL/TLS are considered insecure nowadays).

Comment: We still get the sameWe have setup all microservices with https and also configured OAuth and still no luck.  How does the PowerShell Add-Ttm command send along the cert to the discovery_service or token service?  Still getting stuck on Add-TtmCdEnvironment...

Comment: The TopologyManager seems to have a CdConnector class that connects to the Content Delivery environment...Could it be that it is not aware or passing in the certificate or ssl info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the customer environment only supports TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2. Need to forced the .Net framework to use these versions by changing the below registry keys on CM server.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

Comment: Thanks Venu!  This did it!  Apparently TLS defaults to 1.0 for Windows machines (and PowerShell), and it needed TLS 1.2....