# DXA 2.2 cms-import.ps1 fails due to Core Service issue

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2

During setup of DXA 2.2 and execution of cms-import.ps1 there is the following error
[image]

Checked what is happening with http://localhost/webservices/CoreService201701.svc
and it works ok, running  http://localhost/webservices/CoreService201701.svc?wsdl
there is

```xml
<wsdl:port name="basicHttp" binding="i0:basicHttp">
<soap:address location="https://{SERVERNAME}/webservices/CoreService201701.svc/basicHttp"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

Placing https://{SERVERNAME} as cmsUrl during execution of script, following error shows
[image]

Any idea why this fails?

Comment: Did you install the Tridion Powershell Core services module? if yes what version,
2nd error message could be related to a certificate
can you try with http://servername?

Comment: The user which you trying to run Powershell command has admin rights in the SDL Tridion Sites, right?

Comment: No, I haven't installed PowerShell core service module. Yes powershell command was run with user which has ADMIN rights both on the machine and in SDL Tridion Sites

Comment: can you try with http with servername?

Comment: Tried several options, with http and https, servername, dns name, etc. During installation of DXA 2.0 on Web 8.5 didn't have this kind of issue. Only difference in installation steps is that https was setup after installation of DXA but now it is setup before DXA

Comment: ah then indeed Http coreservice endpoint will not work, I did install it's working but only on Http setup, then it's related to https certificate related to this issue, double-check certificate is valid?

Comment: We have tried with rolling-back web.config file of core service, testing certificate and for cm website its showing as correct one. I will probably do the installation from scratch but without https setup before dxa installation...

Comment: The problem might be caused by TLS 1.2. See https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19902/discovery-service-using-https/19909#19909